# intelliJ idea java certificate

Tags: java, intellij-idea, certificate, keytool

I installed SSL certificate for Jira to Java via keytool. Actually i am using playframework 2 for development and if I use play terminal to compile and run project, everything is fine. The problem appears when I want to use debugger from IntelliJ idea. Project in IDE has set same java as SDK in project setting, but it has not accept the installed certificate. Can somebody help with this?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. What is the problem? Are you pointing the application to the correct keystore/trustore? Please include any exception stacktrace and/or error messages you are receiving...

Comment: application is pointing to correct java folder with set certificate yes. As I said when I run application via terminal everything is fine. But there is no debug option, so I want to run this project via IntelliJ IDEA IDE. But with this configuration java is not accept set certificate and i get this exception in console: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Answer (score 4):

For Mac:
Preferences > Tools > Server Certificates **then** Accept non-trusted Certificates Automatically

[image: See below screenshot]

Comment: This worked for me on Windows.

Comment: Great to hear that it worked for you.

Answer (score 2):

I terms of adding certificate
IntelliJ IDEA -> Preferences -> Tools ->  Server Certificates -> Accepted Certificates -> Add (+)

Comment: Thanks. Once you add the certificate how to access that in Java?  i.e. how to get it's path?

Answer (score 0):

Go to File->Settings>Tools>Server Certificates. In the IDE Settings section select Server Certificates

Myself I just selected the Accept Automatically check box, hit Apply and never had to deal with it. If you are worried about security, there is also the option to add them 1 at a time as they come up.

In my case I did this because I already had a *.google.com certificate configured as accepted, but I still got the popup. I suspect that the fingerprint changed and if I would have deleted and then accepted the error would have gone away, but I decided to just make it go away by selecting the check box.

Answer (score -4):

Go to File -> Settings -> Tools -> Server Certificates , and check the box "Accept non-trusted Certificates Automatically". That might solve your problem.
Also check your jdk version. I had to change to 1.8.0_192 on my Intellij.

Comment: It's not a good idea to allow all non-trusted certificates automatically. If you do this anyway, keep in mind it's not secure.